# How To Pass cuDF Dataframe to cuML.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier?

Tags: python, random-forest, cudf

I'm trying to fit data to the `cuml.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier` and I keep getting the error: "The labels need to be consecutive values from 0 to the number of unique label values"

I'm passing cudf.DataFrame objects into the function which have the same number of rows but differing number of columns. The column labels start at 0 and step by 1 up to the final column (in the example below 108). What am I doing wrong? I've attached a printout of the dataframes that I'm passing in below and some code for context:

`clf1 = modelClass(max_depth=D1, random_state=random.randrange(0, 1024, 1),  n_bins=15, n_streams=4, split_criterion=criterion, bootstrap=bootstrap, n_estimators=trs1)`

`clf1.fit(X1, Y1)`

X1's dataframe looks like this:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.000000e-11 | 1.000000e-11 | 1.647421e-01 |
| 1 | 1.000000e-11 | 1.000000e-11 | 1.760000e-02 |
| 2 | 1.000000e-11 | 1.000000e-11 | -1.772000e-01 |
| 3 | 1.000000e-11 | 1.000000e-11 | 8.254000e-01 |
| 4 | 1.000000e-11 | 1.000000e-11 | 2.587000e-01 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 5402 | 1.000000e-11 | 1.000000e-11 | 1.704444e-01 |
| 5403 | 1.000000e-11 | 1.000000e-11 | -1.860000e-01 |
| 5404 | 0.000000e+00 | 1.000000e-11 | 1.229714e-01 |
| 5405 | 1.000000e-11 | 1.959500e-01 | 1.984667e-01 |
| 5406 | 1.000000e-11 | 1.000000e-11 | 1.000000e-11 |

[5407 rows x 3 columns]; dtype=('0', dtype('float64')); <cudf.core.dataframe._DataFrameLocIndexer object at 0x7f9c3d0f3070>

Y1's Dataframe looks like this:

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | -2.0 |
| 1 | 4.0 |
| 2 | -3.0 |
| 3 | 1.0 |
| 4 | 0.0 |
| ... | ... |
| 5402 | 0.0 |
| 5403 | -2.0 |
| 5404 | 0.0 |
| 5405 | 0.0 |
| 5406 | 0.0 |

[5407 rows x 1 columns]; dtype=('0', dtype('float64')); <cudf.core.dataframe._DataFrameLocIndexer object at 0x7f9c1b847b50>

System Information: Ubuntu 20.04, Titan RTX, CUDA 11.5, Rapids 21.12 built-in Conda, Python 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up that you need to encode Y1's Dataframe first before passing it:

```
enc = cuml.preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

Y1 = enc.fit_transform(Y1)
```

Shoutout to @beckernick for helping me out with this!